# Reflection type load exception when adding a class to ptoject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, system.reflection

Im currently developing a c# wpf app, it works fine until i add a vhd c++ wrapper class to my project, witch is pritty large so im not posting it here and it works fine by itself. In my project when add class file and run my program i get an error in entity framework at this line

```
CDEnteties.Services.Add(service);
```

i get an error {"Could not load type 'STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_Union' from assembly 'cloud opeaner, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.":"STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_Union"} i dont have any idea how those 2 are related and why its happening.

EDIT:
stack trace

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
at System.Data.EntityUtil.GetTypesSpecial(Assembly assembly)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
at cloud_opeaner.OAtuhStorage.storeService(Service& service) in e:\pytons\projects c#\vs12 test\cloud opeaner\cloud opeaner\OAuthStorage.cs:line 105
at cloud_opeaner.SkyDrive..ctor() in e:\pytons\projects c#\vs12 test\cloud opeaner\cloud opeaner\SkyDrive.cs:line 51
at cloud_opeaner.MainWindow.Button_Click_1(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in e:\pytons\projects c#\vs12 test\cloud opeaner\cloud opeaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 87
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at cloud_opeaner.App.Main() in e:\pytons\projects c#\vs12 test\cloud opeaner\cloud opeaner\App.xaml.cs:line 24
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: EF is trying to load types that match the model. The way it is done is to probe all types from the assembly. Try putting the type in a separate assembly. Btw. how your wrapper class is supposed to work in a .NET project if the type cannot be loaded?

Comment: Im not sure what are you asking, i found a small sample app that i can compile under framework 4.5 and works fine. When i add that code to my app i get the error, code is here i just changed the namespace and class name http://pastebin.com/X5tmCEiL

Comment: I am asking if you are able to use the code you imported - especially the GetStorageDependencyInformation method? There is something wrong with they alignment of the types (this is done to match native structs/unions). I believe that the 'STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_Union' type has a problem but since you are not using it CLR does not try loading it and you don't see the problem. To confirm - in your app before you use EF (or create a test app without EF) - put `Console.WriteLine(typeof('STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_Union').FullName);` Do you see the same exception?

Comment: sorry for the wait, i added code line to the class `Console.WriteLine(typeof(NativeMethods.STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_Union).FullName);` and then called it. Got an exception {"Could not load type 'STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_Union' from assembly 'cloud opeaner take1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.":"STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_Union"}. So is that structure the root of the problem?

Comment: Seems to. If you don't use the method that needs this structure I would just try removing/commenting it out and try again (note that other structures might have a similar problem). Another option would be to fix the structure so that it's correct but it's been years since I did native programming so don't know from top of my head how to fix it.

Comment: ty, its ok. I know some native programming, was just hoping i would save some time and didnt have to pick apart the class from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not related to EF per se. You seem to have an invalid type in your assembly and EF just touches it and therefore it blows. If you try to load this type manually (e.g. `Console.WriteLine(typeof('STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_Union').FullName);`) you will see the same exception even if you don't have EF in your project. You need to fix the type or remove it (along with code that depend on it) if you don't use it.